# Tomcat 7 failed to start configured in eclipse

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I have tomcat 7 setup in eclipse and when I start it trows the following stack trace.I have already tried changing the port numbers but no luck. Does anyone else has also faced the same problem?

```
Nov 06, 2015 1:30:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-1003]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-1003]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: create
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:308)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:649)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok So finally I have figured out why tomcat is not starting up. I am running tomcat through my citrix profile and there are 2 drives C and G which I am accessing. G drive is  where my workspace resides and in installed JRE I am referring to the java which is also in my G drive. When I changed the java path in intalled JRE to the one which is in C drive tomcat got started.

Hence the conclusion is there could be some permission issues which are restricting java to access some resources required to start tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to run any Web Application or it is throwing the exception while starting the tomcat itself. 
here we have two solutions one is either any exception in your web.xml or your tomcat problem, i mean to say version problem or any file missing in tomcat root directory.so try with different sub version of tomcat7.